# Insufficient privilege error on integrated app

Tags: integration, connected-apps

I have integrated QlikSense in SalesForce.com sales cloud using SAML authentication. I am giving individual users access to a permission set but they are seeing following error.

Error: The webpage at https://my-hub-url/sfdc/sense/app/my-app-abcd might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

What I am trying to achieve is

1. Tab visible to 8 users only.
2. Only 8 users have access to this connected app.

Answer (score 0):

You are most  likely missing the profile level permission while creating permission set.

Comment: if you are not 100% sure, this would be better suited as a comment until confirmed by the OP.